# ANDROID: Async error "An error occured while executing doInBackground()"

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm using async tasks to get info from an api server and update the UI. However I get an error at this line of the code:

```
public Drawable[] getSummonerSpells(int game) throws JSONException, IOException {
    Drawable drawable[] = new Drawable[] {null, null};
    Bitmap bd = null;
    int spell1 = 0, spell2 = 0;
    if(jsonSummonerRecentGames!=null){
        JSONArray array = jsonSummonerRecentGames.getJSONArray("games");
        if((game) <= array.length()) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(game - 1);
            if(object.has("spell1")) {
                spell1 = object.getInt("spell1");
            }
            if(object.has("spell2")){
                spell2 = object.getInt("spell2");
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/summoner-spell/" + spell1 + "?api_key=9ed10e48-7ac1-422e-b3d0-fd75dedcc3b2");
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = httpClient.execute(get); *********ERROR HERE*********
    HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    String key = jsonObject.getString("key");
    try        {
        URL url2 = new URL("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.2.1/img/spell/" + key + ".png");
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url2.openStream());
        bd = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch(Exception e2){}
    if(bd != null){
        drawable[0] = new BitmapDrawable(bd);
    }
    url = new StringBuilder("https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/summoner-spell/" + spell2 + "?api_key=9ed10e48-7ac1-422e-b3d0-fd75dedcc3b2");
    get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    r = httpClient.execute(get);
    e = r.getEntity();
    data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    key = jsonObject.getString("key");
    try        {
        URL url2 = new URL("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.2.1/img/spell/" + key + ".png");
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url2.openStream());
        bd = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch(Exception e2){}
    if(bd != null){
        drawable[1] = new BitmapDrawable(bd);
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

When I debug it, the URL that is put in is this :

https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/summoner-spell/12?api_key=9ed10e48-7ac1-422e-b3d0-fd75dedcc3b2

and this website gives an JSON response back.

I call this method in my doInBackground() method for the async task here:

```
        Drawable[] summonerSpell = null;
        try {
            summonerSpell = data.getSummonerSpells(2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the async task is called from my first async task here:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        new BackgroundStuffGameOne().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, dataClass);
        new BackgroundStuffGameTwo().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, dataClass);
    }
```

Any ideas as to why this error is called? Thanks :)

Comment: Where do you initialize `httpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

From the code in the question, it looks like `httpClient` is not getting initialized.

If you already have it declared (which it seems that you do), you can just initialize it before you use it:

```
 httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); //Added
 StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/summoner-spell/" + spell1 + "?api_key=9ed10e48-7ac1-422e-b3d0-fd75dedcc3b2");
 HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
 HttpResponse r = httpClient.execute(get); //Should work now
```

Also, just to note, make sure that you have the `INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

One more thing to note, `DefaultHttpClient` [has been deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) for a good guide to using `HTTPUrlConnection`, which is a good replacement.